# Facilities to work with datetime format in R: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS-0200

Tags: python, r, pandas, datetime-format

I have a datetime string in a format of `27.04.2020 15:50:30.391-0700`. `0700` after dash was to denote the timezone relative to GMT.

I found it kind of annoying in `R` as there is no known tools to work with this type of non-standard datetime format. I use R way more than python on a daily basis, yet `pandas` is just very intuitive to use for this and `pandas` can actually do time diff directly on these format when they are proper python `datetime` objects. R, as of this minute I could not figure out a way to do it; I've experimented quite a bit of string replacing, as.character and more (to no avail).

Can anyone prove me wrong?

Comment: Can you try `library(lubridate);dmy_hms(str1)`

Comment: I tried that; it simply ignored millisecond and returned seconds only; apart from this it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change display options to see the milliseconds. Try this one:

```
library(lubridate)

time_string <- '27.04.2020 15:50:30.391-0700'
time_lubridate <- dmy_hms(time_string)
options(digits.secs=3)
time_lubridate

> time_lubridate
[1] "2020-04-27 22:50:30.391 UTC"
```